# Cplex Configuration with Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse-cdt, cplex

I am trying to configure the Eclipse CDT with Cplex. 
I have followed the following steps:

- Defined the IL_STD preprocessor macro
- Givent the path of **include** directories in cplex, opl and concert
- Given the path of "**lib**" folder in "**concert**" "**cplex**" and "**opl**" folder
- I have also given the path of **.a** and **.so** files in these directories
  But now when I try to compile my code, it is not able to find the library and give errors like this:

  > `g++ -L/home/randomuser/IBMCplex/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic 
  >   -L/home/randomuser/IBMCplex/concert/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic -o "CplexTest"  ./src/CplexTest.o   -l/home/randomuser/IBMCplex/concert/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/libconcert.a
  >   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/randomuser/IBMCplex/concert/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/libconcert.a
  >   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  >   makefile:45: recipe for target 'CplexTest' failed
  >   make: *** [CplexTest] Error 1`

Can anyone guide me what am I missing here or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-l` option to `g++` does not expect a path as argument. It expects a library name, from which it will form a filename by prepending `lib`, appending `.a` (or `.so` for a dynamic library), and then look for that filename in the paths specified with `-L`.

So, when entering your library name, instead of using the full path `/home/randomuser/IBMCplex/concert/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/libconcert.a`, you should just enter `concert` (on the command line it should be `-lconcert`).